# awk - get input from both file and STDIN?

Tags: awk, input

Is it possible to get input from both file and the terminal?
I wish to ask the user something in the `END` portion of the awk script.

That input should be typed in by the user and not read from the file which had the data to be processed.

```
END {
  getline choice
  if(choice == "Y")
    print "OK"
}
```

But choice is read off the input file.

Comment: `awk` was not really designed for interactive use.  You can pass choice directly to `awk` like `awk -f script.awk -v choice=Y`, and use a wrapper shell script to do the interactive part.  If you really need to wait until the `END` block to ask for `choice`, you could try `getline < "/dev/tty"` as a not terribly portable workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read from `/dev/tty` or from `/dev/stdin`.

```
getline choice < "/dev/tty"
```

`/dev/tty` is pretty ubiquitous (even one the very few, along with `/dev/null` and `/dev/console` to be required by POSIX), `/dev/stdin` is less common, but at least GNU awk would recognize it as meaning stdin even if the system doesn't have such a device/special file.

On Linux (and Cygwin, but not other Unix-likes), reading from `/dev/stdin` is not the same as reading from stdin (fd 0), but instead means reading from the same file as open on fd 0. If that file is a regular file for instance, that would start reading from the start of the file instead of where fd 0 currently points to in the file.

Because GNU `awk` handles paths like `/dev/stdin` by itself (and treat it as reading from stdin), on Linux or Cygwin it would behave differently from other applications that don't do that special handling. If you wanted the Linux/Cygwin behaviour in `gawk` (which here is likely not your case), you could either use `///dev/stdin` or `/dev/./stdin` for `gawk` to stop recognising it as the `/dev/stdin` special case, or probably better here if you intend to rely on Linux/Cygwin specific behaviour, use the Linux/Cygwin specific `/proc/self/fd/0` path (which `/dev/stdin` actually symlinks to on those systems).

Answer (score 3):

As [can be seen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12907310), `-` also works:

```
getline < "-"
```

Or

```
getline variable < "-"
```